# Android Pausing and Resuming Tutorial

Tags: java, android, memory, garbage-collection

I'm having some difficulty figuring out the best ways to pause and resume my application. Is there any comprehensive tutorial or something similar that would help me make sure that I'm not missing any important steps?

Mostly I'm just worried about not dealing with the memory being used by my application. There's a few apps I own that when you minimize them slow down the rest of the phone to a stand still and I want to make sure to avoid that.

Thanks, any help or suggestions on the topic would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

a must-read tutorial

Comment: Thanks, I read that a while ago, but I forgot about the information on saving states.